# update is not working mongodb, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I am creating multiplayer game, where I have login system as well. I want to update my user's rating using `db.collection.update()`, but it is not working. There is no error, just when I write username of my player It says **"Unknown User"**. I write it in my app.js. Besides app.js I have 3 more files for my user.

My **app.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var fs = require('fs');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var User = require('./models/users');

// Init App
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);


// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
  User.getUserByRating(rating, function(err)
      {
        if(err) throw err;
      });

   });
  }));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
   console.log(req.user);
  next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

User.collection.update(
{ username: "example2" },
{
   name: "qq",
   rating: 1
}
)
```

My **users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

    var User = require('../models/users');

    // Register
    router.get('/register', function(req, res){
        res.render('register');
    });


    // Login
    router.get('/login', function(req, res){
        res.render('login');
    });

    //Register User
    router.post('/register', function(req, res){
        var name = req.body.name;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var password2 = req.body.password2;
        var rating =   req.body.rating; 

    // Validation
        req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors)
        {
            res.render('register',{
                errors:errors
            });

        } else 
        {
            var newUser = new User({
                name: name,
                email:email,
                username: username,
                password: password,
                rating: 1000
            });

            User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(user);
            });

            req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');

            res.redirect('/users/login');
        }
    });

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });

    router.post('/login',
      passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
      function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
      });       

    router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logout();

        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');

        res.redirect('/users/login');
    });


    module.exports = router;
```

My **model(again users.js, but in another folder)**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


    var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            index:true
        },
        password: {
            type: String
        },
        email: {
            type: String
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        rating:
        {
            type: Number
        }
    });

    var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);




    module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                newUser.password = hash;
                newUser.save(callback);
            });
        });
    }

    module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
        var query = {username: username};
        User.findOne(query, callback);
    }

    module.exports.getUserByRating = function(rating, callback){
        User.findOne({ rating : rating}, callback);
    }

    module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
        User.findById(id, callback);
    }

    module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
            if(err) throw err;
            callback(null, isMatch);
        });
    }
```

My **index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Get Homepage
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
    } else {
       //req.flash('error_msg','You are not logged in');
       res.redirect('/users/login');
   }
   }


    module.exports = router;
```

Thanks a lot in advance. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: too long. add [mcve], please

Answer (score 1):

Your update code uses raw mongo interface:

```
User.collection.update(
{ username: "example2" },
{
   name: "qq",
   rating: 1
}
)
```

This code replace your document as whole(all missed fields like `password` and etc will be lost).
You may be want to use followed:  `{$set: {name: 'qq', rating: 1}}`

Or use mongoose interface:

```
User.update({username: 'example2'}, {name: 'qq', rating: 1});
```

It will add `$set` part automatically, if you don't specify `safe = false` in your model.

---

*Check actual database state before you start to do anything in your code. There are some users incosistent with your model schema, and may be no user with `example2` name.*

Comment: Thanks for your respond. When I write `User.update({username: 'example4'}, {name: 'qq', rating: 1});` it just doesn't change anything. I can log in with that account, but nothing changes.

Comment: log into mongo REPL and inspect `db.User.find({username: 'example4'})`.

Comment: When I log into my mongo shell there is no User available.It displays my user when I wirte `db.users.find({username: 'example4'})`, because my collection's name is "users". However, when I write `users.update` in my app.js there is an error saying "users.update is not a function". Thanks for your respond again.

Comment: Another interesting thing, when I write `db.users.update({username: 'example4'})`,in mongo shell, it says that example4 was modified, but when I write `db.users.find({username: 'example4'})`, there is no user with that username.Thanks.

Comment: Mongoose transforms model to collection name with pluralize(`User->users`). It's ok.
`db.users.find()` show you all users. may be you replace it with empty document(`db.users.update({username: 'example4'})` w/o second argument).

Comment: In REPL, `update` is replace by default, while you do not specify `{$set: {...}}`

Comment: `User.update({username: 'example4'}, {name: 'qq', rating: 1})` must set `name` and `rating` of first user with `username: 'example4'. You can also `find()` user, set some properties and then call `.save()` on it.

Comment: Sorry, but when I write `User.update({username: 'example4'}, {name: 'qq', rating: 1})` in my **app.js**, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, I found another solution, but thanks for your help:).